# context processor can not pass data

Tags: python, django

i made context_processors to pass data (objects of 'League' class) to 'base.html' but when i clicked on one of anchor tags (that contain league object) it produced " TypeError 'League' object is not iterable "

i tried to pass data to 'base.html' .... to provide pass this data to all views
'context_processors.py'

```
from .models import League
def add_to_base(request):
    return {
        'league' : League.objects.all()
    }
'base.html'
    <div id="league-container">

      {% for l in   league   %}
          <a href="{% url 'core:openleague' l.pk %}"><h2>{{ l.leagues }}</h2></a>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  this is view function
    def openleague(request, pk):
       league = League.objects.get(pk=pk)
       news = league.news.filter(publication_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-publication_date')[:20]
       return render(request, 'core/openleague.html', {'league':league,'news':news})

and this is traceback
Support
TypeError at /11/openleague/ by Django
New
About
Yours
API
Help
4.2 KB, Python console session
    Unwrap Raw text Duplicate


Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/11/openleague/

Django Version: 2.1.4
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
['core.apps.CoreConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django_social_share']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /home/omar/my-django/arena/templates/base.html, error at line 36
   'League' object is not iterable
   26 :     
   27 :        
   28 :        
   29 :        <li><a href="{% url 'core:home' %}" >الرئيسية</a></li>
   30 :      </ul>
   31 :      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
   32 :        <h4>logged in as {{ user.username }}</h4>
   33 :      {% endif %}
   34 :      <div id="league-container">
   35 : 
   36 :        {% for l in  league  %} 
   37 :           <a href="{% url 'core:openleague' l.pk %}"><h2>{{ l.leagues }}</h2></a>
   38 :       {% endfor %}
   39 :     </div>
   40 :     </nav>
   41 : 
   42 :           <main>
   43 :           {% block content %}
   44 :         {% endblock %}
   45 :       </main>
   46 : 


Traceback:

File "/home/omar/my-django/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/omar/my-django/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/omar/my-django/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/omar/my-django/arena/core/views.py" in openleague
  31.     return render(request, 'core/openleague.html', {'league':league,'news':news})

File "/home/omar/my-django/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/home/omar/my-django/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/home/omar/my-django/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/home/omar/my-django/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  171.                     return self._render(context)

File "/home/omar/my-django/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/omar/my-django/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/omar/my-django/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/omar/my-django/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/home/omar/my-django/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/omar/my-django/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/omar/my-django/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/omar/my-django/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  165.                 values = list(values)

Exception Type: TypeError at /11/openleague/
Exception Value: 'League' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback and the view.

Comment: Perhaps you use `league` for a single object in a view. It would be better to use `leagues` in the context processor and `{% for l in leagues %}`.

Comment: {% for l in leagues %} 
this leagues is afield (for name) in League model

Comment: Alsadir ... i added traceback and view function

Comment: this is context_processors.py 
def add_to_base(request):
    return {
        'league' : League.objects.all()
    }
`
what should i change in it ?

Comment: When you get the error, league is a single League instance. Change the context processor to `return {'leagues': ...}`, then change the loop in the template as I suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a context_processor.py in your app

```
from .models import League
def add_to_base(request):
    return {
        'league_from_processor' : League.objects.all()
    }
```

In the project setting add settings.py add this in TEMPLATES => OPTIONS => `context_processors` list

```
    "app_name.context_processor.add_to_base",
```

'base.html'

```
<div id="league-container">

  {% for l in   league_from_processor   %}
      <a href="{% url 'core:openleague' l.pk %}"><h2>{{ l.leagues }}</h2></a>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

More help here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7nwFr4FrEP4

Comment: ok Ben ... i did it but when i clicked anchor tag to open any league (any object of League model) it returned 'League' object is not iterable 
knowing that {{ l.leagues }}     leagues ( name of leagues objects 
<a href="{% url 'core:openleague' l.pk %}"><h2>{{ l.leagues }}</h2></a>

Comment: i think the problem is how to send l.pk to 'core:openleague'

Comment: The problem is inside your second view you pass another variable named league. So django try to loop over it, but in that case it's just one single instance. Try to rename the league dictionary in the context to another name that will not be used elsewhere in your code